# How to export object to xml string without additional data

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have inside my class inner class with four public fields and I want to export to XML string.

I am doing at the moment like (I am using xstream library)

```
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    String xml = xstream.toXML(c);// c is instance of inner class
```

This exports but how to export without package name and additional info, I just need field name and value without additional data. How to do that using xstream library ?
Or to write manually ?

Comment: `xstream.alias("name", MyClass.class);`

Answer (score 0):

With xstream you can make alias,

```
xstream.alias("desiredName", MyClass.class);
```

Read more in this [tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/alias-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [annotations](http://xstream.codehaus.org/annotations-tutorial.html) for [aliasing](http://xstream.codehaus.org/alias-tutorial.html), which is my preferred method. Add these 2 lines before your class;

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;

@XStreamAlias("name")
public class Blabla{

}
```

And than in your 'main' function;

```
    xstream.processAnnotations(Blabla.class);
```